# ARM execute code from embedded RAM

Tags: linker, arm, embedded, ram, execute

I can easily place some of my code RO sections at specific execution regions at specific addresses (which might be RAM addresses). There will be no problem in my program integrity because of proper linking.
The problem is that those RO sections placed at RAM addresses will not appear on RAM after power off/power on. They will be missing. Am I right?
Of course I can load them in place with bootloader, but it is not the case now.
My question is: is there any trusted default method to solve this problem? Maybe some attributes etc. For example, maybe there is method of copying RO sections (like RW) at startup by C library?

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka11494.html
As this post suggest, it is incorrect. As I mentioned before, after restart RAM will not contain any RO data.

Answer (score 2):

You already have this problem in an embedded system with the .data area.  .bss just gets zeroed in the bootstrap, but .data needs to be in non volatile storage so it is there when you power up, but it needs to live in ram.  The typical solution is to mark it as such in the linker script as I normally run from ram but want to be stored in the binary in rom.

with gnu tools you do the something at something thing

```
MEMORY
{
    bob : ORIGIN = 0x8000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ted : ORIGIN = 0xA000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > bob
   __data_rom_start__ = .;
   .data : {
    __data_start__ = .;
    *(.data*)
   } > ted AT > bob
   __data_end__ = .;
   __data_size__ = __data_end__ - __data_start__;
   .bss  : {
   __bss_start__ = .;
   *(.bss*)
   } > bob
   __bss_end__ = .;
   __bss_size__ = __bss_end__ - __bss_start__;
}
```

Linker scripts or other ways of controlling the linker are very specific to the toolchain, I wouldnt automatically expect arms tools to use the same solution as gnus tools or other tools.  They might to keep the rest of us sane, but it is not something a standards body manages.

then you have to match your bootstrap code to the linker script scheme and copy the data over.

if you have sections of code you want to move and not just data or instead of data you would use the exact same scheme, add linker script things to mark that blob of code as want to live here when run but want to live there in the binary image.  and your bootstrap or some code has to copy that fraction of the program to ram before it is used.

Answer (score 2):

It is (amongst other tasks) the responsibility of the C runtime start-up code (that which runs before `main()` is executed) to copy RAM executable code from the ROM image to RAM.  In some cases the ROM image may be compressed so that the start-up code must also perform decompression.

Your tool-chain may already provide suitable start-up code, or you may have to modify the existing runtime start-up code to support this.